# Double-click to open in external editor in Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

In Xcode 3 there was a preference to choose which external editor you wanted particular file types to open in. I could open .m files in TextMate if I wanted to do something quick using that editor. That preference is gone in Xcode 4. Before, I could single-click on a file in the navigator to have it open in Xcode, or double click to have it open in my chosen editor. In Xcode 4, a double click opens a window with a big icon. This is especially useless for sqlite files:

[image]

Of course, I can right-click on a file in the navigator and choose "Open with External Editor", but I'd like to be able to just double-click. Is there any way to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?